# How to get the fields of a JSON object in android studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-edittext

I have an android app and a Web Service. When I want to edit some register I have to get the whole record from the database and put every field in a Edit Text.

The Web Service return me this to the android app

```
[{"id":"6","0":"6","tipo":"No Oxidado","1":"No Oxidado","fecha":"2015-02-02","2":"2015-02-02","ubicacion":"-1.555505, -6.6171","3":"-1.555505, -6.6171","persona":"Laura Morales","4":"Laura Morales","fotografia":"-","5":"-"}]
```

And I have a variable called "result" that have this JSON string

How do I put every field in a independent edit text in my Android App?

something like:

```
txtid.setText(result[0]);
txtType.setText(result[1]);
txtDate.setText(result[2]);
txtLocation.setText(result[3]);
txtPerson.setText(result[4]);
```

where "result" is my JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code.

if you have more than one json object in array

```
String response = "[{"id":"6","0":"6","tipo":"No Oxidado","1":"No Oxidado","fecha":"2015-02-02","2":"2015-02-02","ubicacion":"-1.555505, -6.6171","3":"-1.555505, -6.6171","persona":"Laura Morales","4":"Laura Morales","fotografia":"-","5":"-"}]"

try {
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
       for (int i =0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
           JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           txtid.setText(jsonObject.getString("0"));
           txtType.setText(jsonObject.getString("1"));
           txtDate.setText(jsonObject.getString("2"));
        }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

And if you have only one object in array then no need to use for loop use directly this way

```
  try {
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

           JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
           txtid.setText(jsonObject.getString("0"));
           txtType.setText(jsonObject.getString("1"));
           txtDate.setText(jsonObject.getString("2"));

     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a library to convert Json object to android model that call `GSON`

at first create a model with your input object like below:

```
class InputModel {
  String id;
  String 0; //it's better to change this object name
  String tipo;
...
}
```

next, you can use `Gson` to bind your input to your model. it should be something like this:

```
InputModel mInput = new Gson().fromJson(data);
```

ps1: data is your input string

ps2: if you want the name of your input be different with your input name, you can use an annotation like this:

```
@SerializedName("id")
String productId;
```